# layout folder changes issue

Tags: java, android, layout

I have two layout folder, Layout and Layout-small. When i change something in Layout-small my values in Layout folder changes too!!! What is this?!? I cant design UI by this way. This is a normal behavior?

Comment: Actually it shouldn't change like that...

Answer (score 1):

When you load your XML layout file in eclipse, make sure you have loaded the correct one. You can check this by hovering over the tab name, and check where the layout is being referenced from.

Make sure you have the same layout file in both folders, and when you open one up, make sure eclipse has not tried to load a different file based on your device configuration. You can always try changing the device configuration to load a small device instead.